# select query with date condition

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I had a issue with select queryI(below) with date condition. Query Not giving proper result, I don't know Why?

Please Help Me Out Thanks In Advance.Created_Date field in database had value between 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-31

```
SELECT * FROM (`cms_product`) WHERE `cms_product`.`Created_Date` >= 2013-01-01 
and `cms_product`.`Created_Date` <= 2013-01-31 ;
```

Created_Date field is in Datetime.

Comment: Date literals must be quoted in single quotes `>= '2013-01-01'` Beyond that, if the column is a DATETIME, you must call `DATE()` to strip off the time part and compare by date alone:  `>= DATE('2013-01-01')`

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use the BETWEEN operator here.

```
SELECT * FROM  (`cms_product`) WHERE  `cms_product`.`Created_Date` BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND ' 2013-01-31 23:59:59.997'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM cms_product WHERE Created_Date >= '2013-01-01' AND Created_Date <= '2013-01-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `cms_product` WHERE `Created_Date` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM cms_product WHERE DATE(Created_Date) BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31';
```